# Unable to make a connection between SQL Server 2005 with asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am an Asp.Net beginner and I am trying to create an web based application. When I am connecting ASP.Net with SQL Server 2005 then it show this the following error on execution of application.

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.
>   When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the
>   fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

Although I tried enough to sought this out but unable to get the solution, now I need your kind help to sought this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** here's my connection string from `web.config`:

```
<add name="cn" 
     connectionString="DataSource=PT-7DBE27DA8;InitialCatalog=Pages;IntegratedSecurity=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: posting your connection string will help us help you.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed true, Anshdeep - just make sure to remove any passwords or sensitive stuff from that string. We just need to see how you try to connect.

Comment: Check your connection string against the examples on http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: <add name="cn" connectionString="DataSource=PT-7DBE27DA8;InitialCatalog=Pages;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>                              "the connection string that i am using in web config file."

Comment: @AnshdeepSingh: please **don't** post code or config into comments - really really hard to read since you cannot format it! Instead: **update** your original question by editing it!!

Answer (score 0):

Make a connection in Visual Studio [Server Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316649) and then click a Test Connection button to be sure that everything is fine.

Then click on database and select properties.
On properties window you can find the correct ConnectionString which you can copy it to your code.

Comment: thank for your kind reply. but i still the same error occurs while execution.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many reasons:

- the host with sql server is unavailable for now (ping it)
- you forgot to notice INSTANCE in conn string (check it)
- sql server is down (check it, run it)
- you use tcpip or netpipes transport, which could be switched off by server configuration (check it)
- there can exists a firewall in the middle between you and sql server (telnet it on 1433 port, uf use tcpip, otherwise - check it), **your case - named pipes** - check the port 445
- and there are many more like this (google it 8-)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx) you can find helpful information how to troubleshoot the problem on your side.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com), you'll see that your connection string is wrong.

You need to use either:

```
Data Source=PT-7DBE27DA8;Initial Catalog=Pages;Integrated Security=True
```

*(notice the **spaces** between `Data` and `Source` and between `Initial` and `Catalog` and between `Integrated` and `Security`)*

or:

```
server=PT-7DBE27DA8;database=Pages;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

This second one is my preferred option - `server` seems so much clearer than `data source` (same goes for `database` vs. `initial catalog`)